# SQL trying to Insert into DB

Tags: php, sql

PHP keeps throwing an error telling me I have a syntax problem but gives no other information, what's up with this?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO objective_form (name, doa, dob, pmuscle_length, palpation, accessory_movements, functional_tests, myotomes, dermatiomes, refles, ntpt, special_tests, working_hypothesis, plan, tx)
 VALUES ('$name', '$doa', '$dob', '$pmuscle_length', '$palpation', '$accessory_movements', '$functional_tests', '$myotomes', '$dermatiomes', '$refles', '$ntpt', '$special_tests, 
 '$working_hypothesis', '$plan', '$tx')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Recorded successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: can you show the exact error message please?

Comment: What is happening if you do "echo $sql" and try to run the code in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot apostrophe sign (') after $special_tests in VALUES line. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO objective_form (name, doa, dob, pmuscle_length, palpation, accessory_movements, functional_tests, myotomes, dermatiomes, refles, ntpt, special_tests, working_hypothesis, plan, tx)
 VALUES ('$name', '$doa', '$dob', '$pmuscle_length', '$palpation', '$accessory_movements', '$functional_tests', '$myotomes', '$dermatiomes', '$refles', '$ntpt', '$special_tests', 
 '$working_hypothesis', '$plan', '$tx')";
```

If that does not work still, please do `echo $sql` and try to run the command in SQL itself, that'd show the location of the syntax error.